# Framework/ guide to image recognition- Augmented Reality

Tags: android, image, augmented-reality, scanning

Is there any existing framework or guide that gives or explains how to have your app recognize an image. So basically suppose the image was a specific bottle, is there framework that allows you to scan the bottle, and then recognize that it is a bottle?

I don't need the whole image overlay stuff or geolocations(so basically only the image recognition half of augmented reality).

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067939/523725

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of them available.

1. [Vuforia](http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality)
2. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)
3. [Metaio](http://www.metaio.com/) (This is paid)