# how to read text from image in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, image-recognition

I need to start camera and scan the image.There are set of predefined images.I need to recognize particular image from camera and need to fire specific event.

Suppose there are 2 types of food packets which has different images on it. When anyone scan this foodpacket then from camera it should be recognized that this is x food packet or this is y food packet and need to play video accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this several questions regarding image recognition:

[java framework for image pattern recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062618/java-framework-for-image-pattern-recognition)

[JAVA OCR API open-source on eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480831/java-ocr-api-open-source-on-eclipse/9481603#9481603)