# Machine learning images

Tags: machine-learning

am a novice to machine learning, and I hope someone will guide me along.
I need to train the machine to recognize a certain object e.g. using libsvm. but i don't know what to specify for the training file and how to even start. can provide me with psuedo code? am a java person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is huge amount of material on the web. Supposedly you'd like to learn something more about field called `image recognition`, or `computer vision` - is that what you need?

some general info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision

java & image recognition:
[java framework for image pattern recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062618/java-framework-for-image-pattern-recognition)

working example
http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html
http://savvash.blogspot.cz/2010/05/simple-image-recognition-in-java.html

there is widely recognize tool Weka (java and ML):
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/
You mentioned SVM (libsvm in particular) this algorithm is included in Weka as well.

and many more ...